# Cannot run openssl with variable in shell script

Tags: shell, openssl

I'm trying to run some `openssl` command with user input. But `openssl` cannot read `variable` value. So I tried to pre-execute the value of variable but didn't work either. `i.e $(echo "'$uinput'")`

**Code:**

```
read uinput
openssl genrsa -out CA.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key CA.key -sha256 -days 60 -out CA.pem -subj '$uinput'
```

**Error**

```
Subject does not start with '/'
```

So I `echo` the final command using the following code:

```
echo "openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key CA.key -sha256 -days 60 -out CA.pem -subj '$uinput'"
```

**Output**

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key CA.key -sha256 -days 60 -out CA.pem -subj '/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Blah Blah/O=abc.com, Inc./CN=ABC DC'
```

When I `copy paste` the output in `terminal`, it works.

Comment: The characters are likely wrong when copy/pasting. Its probably one of those slanted double quotes rather than the old style double quotes. Another one to look out for when copy/pasting is the dash versus the long em-hyphen (I think that's what it is called).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It's shell script. I hope it's related to programming.

Comment: Got here way late and for a completely unrelated problem, but the issue in this one is the single quotes around `$uinput`. The command _looks_ correct when you `echo` it because you're wrapping the entire command string in double quotes, which causes bash to do the expansion.